# Checkbox returned in Event Handler isn't one on form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, inheritance

I'm creating an array of checkboxes on a form dynamically; the code that creates the array looks like this:-

```
checkbox_array(count_of_checkboxes) = New CheckBox

if (count_of_checkboxes = 0) Then
    checkbox_array(count_of_checkboxes).Top = specimen_checkbox.Top
    checkbox_array(count_of_checkboxes).Left = specimen_checkbox.Left
else
    checkbox_array(count_of_checkboxes).Top = checkbox_array(count_of_checkboxes - 1).Top + vertical_offset
    checkbox_array(count_of_checkboxes).Left = checkbox_array(count_of_checkboxes - 1).Left + horizontal_offset
End If

my_panel.Controls.Add(checkbox_array(count_of_checkboxes))
AddHandler checkbox_array(count_of_checkboxes).MouseClick, cbxSpecimen_CheckedChanged

checkbox_array(count_of_checkboxes).Name    = someValue
checkbox_array(count_of_checkboxes).Text    = someValue
checkbox_array(count_of_checkboxes).Enabled = true
checkbox_array(count_of_checkboxes).Visible = true
checkbox_array(count_of_checkboxes).Show()
```

This works fine and dandy on one form. However, I am using the same code on a form which is derived from a base form, and running into a problem, in that the object returned in the `sender` parameter, although clearly a checkbox with a recognisable name, isn't any of the checkboxes in the array.

I verified this with:-

```
Private Sub cbxSpecimen_CheckedChanged( sender As System.Object,  e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbxSpecimen.CheckedChanged
For i As Integer = 0 To checkbox_array.GetUpperBound(0) - 1
    If checkbox_array(i).Equals(sender) Then
        // set a breakpoint here
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Can anyone shed any light on why this should work on a normal form, but not a derived-class form?

Comment: There's no sign of you actually adding check boxes to the array.  You never increment *count_of_checkboxes*.

Comment: @HansPassant, that is done but not in the bit shown, which is illustrative (I hope), as there is quite a bit of other stuff around. I don't think I've left out anything related to the problem, although some purely mechanical parts are omitted.

Comment: You have `Handles cbxSpecimen.CheckedChanged` on the end of your handler, which means it is handling a CheckBox that was added to the form at design-time (or was declared as `WithEvents` in code?).  Maybe that design-time CheckBox is in the exact location location of one of the dynamic ones, but "on top"?

Answer (score 1):

> I verified this with:-

```
Private Sub cbxSpecimen_CheckedChanged( sender As System.Object,  e As System.EventArgs) 
  Handles cbxSpecimen.CheckedChanged
    For i As Integer = 0 To checkbox_array.GetUpperBound(0) - 1
        If checkbox_array(i).Equals(sender) Then
            // set a breakpoint here
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Why `checkbox_array.GetUpperBound(0) - 1`? This will skip the last element in the array.  Try:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To checkbox_array.GetUpperBound(0)
        If checkbox_array(i).Equals(sender) Then
            // set a breakpoint here
        End If
    Next i
```

Or

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To checkbox_array.Length - 1
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That wasn't the problem, although it might well have been.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get this to work by refilling the array of checkboxes inside the click event:-

```
Private Sub cbxSpecimen_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbxSpecimen.CheckedChanged
    For i As Integer = 0 To check_boxes.GetUpperBound(0)
        If check_box_array(i).Name = CType(sender, CheckBox).Name And
           Not check_box_array(i).Equals(sender) Then
            check_box_array(i) = CType(sender, CheckBox)
        End If
    Next i
    ' do useful work
End Sub
```

After the check box on the form has been stuffed back into the array, it remains there (so the second invokation for the same checkbox doesn't insert into the array a second time).

This seems like a ghastly hack to me, but I'll go with it for the time being.